# How to use multiple arguments in symfony2 service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

This is my  service file code

```
adminusercheck.commonFunc:
        class:        adminBundle\Helpers\CommonFunctions
        #arguments: ["@session"]        

        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
            - @session
```

This is my Service class code

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
class CommonFunctions{

    private $session;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
         $this->em = $em;
    }
```

Comment: Please can you explain what problem you are having? Are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to adminBundle\Helpers\CommonFunctions::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in

Answer (score 0):

Your argument order in the `constructor` is not matching with what's inside the services file.

The following,

```
public function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $em)
```

Needs to be,

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, Session $session)
```

It is essential to note that argument order is important.

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/dependency_injection.html

On a separate note, try to keep DI's to the minimum as possible. This will have an impact on performance.

Hope this helps. Thanks.